# Why does stream filter not work in the below code snippet

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider below code snippet and it gives `null`; Could you please help on this:

```
//model class
public class Author {
    private String name;
    private int countOfBooks;
    // setters and getters left for brevity
}

//model class
public class Book {
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private Author author;
    // setters and getters left for brevity
}
```

Now, let us say that we want to *filter* out books published in or before 2005. We wouldd probably *filter* twice, as follows:

```
// main class 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Author> authors = Arrays.asList(new Author("Venkat", 10),new Author("Richord", 8));

    List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(new Book("Venkat", 2006, new Author()));

    books.stream()
         .filter(book -> book.getYear() > 2005)  // filter out books published in or before 2005
         .map(Book::getAuthor)                   // get the list of authors for the remaining books
         .filter(Objects::nonNull)               // remove null authors from the list
         .map(Author::getName)                   // get the list of names for the remaining authors
         .forEach(System.out::println);          // print the value of each remaining element
}
```

Comment: In your `new Book(...)` constructor call: `,new Author()` -> null name String

Comment: what do you think will happen in `Author::getName` is name is actually null?

Comment: Could you please , explain with example

Comment: Just try on your test book object first to `getAuthor` and then `getName` of the author.

Comment: you are true @Eugen , now got outcome, Thanks

Comment: What is the `Author`'s  name in this statement? `new Book("Venkat",2006,new Author())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you are trying is intending to print author names for books with year greater than 2005. This requires some example data - books with a mix of years (for the purpose of filtering some data based on year) and authors with names.

There are two classes: `Author` and `Book`. Lets create some example data for these:

Authors:

Author has two attributes - name, book count. Lets create two author objects. Note the authors have names:

- name = "H. G. Wells", book count = 2.
- name = "Harper Lee", book count = 1.

Books:

Book has three attributes - name, year and author. Lets create three book objects:

- name = "War of the Worlds", year = 1898, author = "H. G. Wells" (the
  author created above: 1).
- name = "The Time Machine", year = 1895, author = "H. G. Wells" (the
  author created above: 1).
- name = "To Kill a Mockingbird", year = 1960, author = "Harper Lee" (the author created above: 2).

Now, build the `Author` objects:

```
Author hgWells = new Author("H. G. Wells", 2);
Author hLee = new Author("Harper Lee", 1);
```

NOTE: An `Author` object can also be built with the following constructor:

```
Author hgWells = new Author();
```

This builds an author object with name value as `null` and book count value as `zero`. These `null` and `zero` are default values for instance variables defined in the `Author` class. So, a call to the `getName()` method returns a `null`.

And, some `Book` objects:

```
Book book1 = new Book("War of the Worlds", 1898, hgWells);
Book book2 = new Book("The Time Machine", 1895, hgWells);
Book book3 = new Book("To Kill a Mockingbird", 1960, hLee);
```

Create a list of books:

```
List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(book1, book2, book3);
System.out.println(books);
```

This will print:

```
[(War of the Worlds, 1898 - H. G. Wells), (The Time Machine, 1895 - H. G. Wells), (To Kill a Mockingbird, 1960 - Harper Lee)]
```

Note the overridden `Object`'s `toString()` method shows all the attribute details of the `Book` objects.

Filter the books:

Now, we have some books with authors data to work with. Lets filter them. In this example I will print books in 20th century (i.e., filter books published with year greater then 1899, between 1900 and 1999; we have books from 19th and 20th century only).

Since we are using streams; a filter is to be a lambda. Here it is:

```
Predicate<Book> yearFilter = book -> book.getYear() > 1899;
```

Lets apply the filter to the list of books:

```
books.stream()
    .filter(yearFilter)
    .map(book -> book.getAuthor().getName())
    .forEach(authorName -> System.out.println(authorName));
```

This will print: *Harper Lee*. There is only one book with its published year in the 20th century - where the year is 1960 and the author's name is printed.

**Comment:**

This is an example to create some test data and use it to work with a stream's filter function.

**The Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;

class Author {

    private String name;
    private int bookCount;

    public Author() {
    }

    public Author(String name, int bookCount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.bookCount = bookCount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getBookCount() {
        return bookCount;
    }
}

class Book {

    private String name;
    private int year;
    private Author author;

    public Book(String name, int year, Author author) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + name + ", " + year + " - " + author.getName() + ")";
    }

}

public class TestingLambdas2 {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Author hgWells = new Author("H. G. Wells", 2);
        Author hLee = new Author("Harper Lee", 1);

        Book book1 = new Book("War of the Worlds", 1898, hgWells);
        Book book2 = new Book("The Time Machine", 1895, hgWells);
        Book book3 = new Book("To Kill a Mockingbird", 1960, hLee);

        List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(book1, book2, book3);
        System.out.println("> All books:" + books);

        Predicate<Book> yearFilter = book -> book.getYear() > 1899;
        System.out.println("> Filtered book author(s):");
        books.stream()
                .filter(yearFilter)
                .map(book -> book.getAuthor().getName())
                .forEach(authorName -> System.out.println(authorName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your conditions on `books.stream()`, you can see that there is a particular condition where you are getting all the authors for your books:

```
.map(Book::getAuthor)              // get the list of authors for the remaining books
```

However, in your declaration of `books`, you declared your book as so:

```
List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(
            new Book("Venkat",2006,new Author())
    );
```

According to your class declaration, this would create a book with title "Venkat", year "2006". For author of the book, you called `new Author()` with no parameters. According to your class declaration for author, this will create an author with null name, and null countOfBooks.

Instead, your book declaration should be something like:

```
List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(
            new Book("Venkat",2006,authors[0])
    );
```

OR

```
List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(
            new Book("Venkat",2006,new Author("Sekhar", 1))
    );
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your time and help on this , It is been resolved @bunbun